# Is this a possible browser quirk with safari and column wrapped flexbox's?

Tags: safari, cross-browser, flexbox

Compare how my flexbox looks in chrome or firefox and how it looks in safari. Chrome & Firefox are correct.

In Safari, It's acting like the minimum height of the flex box is calculated based on the bottom position of the last flex item, whereas in other browsers it seems to calculate the minimum height of the flex box based upon any flex item which takes it over the minimum.

Can anybody find out if my code is wrong or confirm that this is a bug?

View snippet in full page to see.

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 984px;
}
.container {
  margin: 0 80px;
  padding: 30px 0;
}
h1 {
  margin: 0;
}
.top {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-height: 800px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.prod-header {
  order: 3;
  width: 49%;
  padding-left: 30px;
}
.prod-header img {
  width: 100%;
}
.my-slider {
  order: 1;
  width: 51%;
  padding-right: 30px;
}
.my-slider img {
  width: 100%;
}
.prod-info {
  order: 4;
  width: 49%;
  padding-left: 30px;
}
.prod-video {
  order: 2;
  width: 51%;
  padding-right: 30px;
}
.prod-video iframe {
  width: 100%;
}
.prod-review {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  order: 5;
  padding-left: 30px;
  width: 49%;
}
.prod-review img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="top flex">
      <header class="prod-header">
        <h1><img src="http://placehold.it/608x300"></h1>
        <p>Family trivia game</p>
      </header>
      <div class="my-slider">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/608x675">
      </div>
      <div class="prod-info">
        <p>Lorem ipsum Occaecat qui proident aute id voluptate velit nulla anim incididunt.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum Velit sint dolore dolor irure ullamco eu. Lorem ipsum Aute irure velit ad in sunt Duis sint veniam minim in labore voluptate. Lorem ipsum Laborum dolore eiusmod Ut deserunt occaecat aliquip amet do esse quis tempor et.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="prod-video">
        <div class="videoWrapper">
          <iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/KqtvA6xo4DE" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="prod-review">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/608x375">
        <a class="button" href="#">Buy now</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is indeed a Safari-specific Bug.